# Iam cannot able to connect parse to my server

Tags: php, parse-platform

Here is my code:

```
<?php 'vendor/autoload.php';
ParseClient::initialize("hidden by my self(app id)", null,hidden by me(masterkey));
ParseClient::setServerURL('http://18.218.104.8:80/parse/','parse');
$health = ParseClient::getServerHealth();
if($health['status'] === 200) {
echo "I have a $color $car.";
}
?>
```

It doesn't connect me to parse dashboard instead of that its showing me:

[image: screenshot]

( my worked is based on [this](https://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/#install-with-composer) )

Comment: `hidden by me(masterkey)` is not a string.  Just saying,  I'm not opening a link to whatever `Error A` is.

Comment: those two things are just for privacy brother because its not my project and hidden by me means string

Comment: can u please clean the code?

Comment: I pulled in that image, but please understand: error messages are **text**. So dont use screen shots, but well formatted/indented *text* for such messages.